# AS3 sound play when hit mc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

I have a script like this

```
 var idsya1:Idsya1 = new Idsya1(); 
    var iqlab1:Iqlab1 = new Iqlab1(); 
    var ikhsya1:Ikhsya1 = new Ikhsya1(); 


    if (idsya_1.hitTestObject(idsyabox_1))
     {
       idsya_1.enabled = false;
      //idsya_1.visible = false;
      idsya_1.buttonMode = false;
      idsya_1.x = 145.30 ;
      idsya_1.y = 168.05;
      idsya1.play();
      score+=10;
      skor.text = " " + score;
         }

     if (iqlab_1.hitTestObject(iqlabbox_1))
     {
       iqlab_1.enabled = false;
    //   iqlab_1.visible = false;
       iqlab_1.buttonMode = false;
       iqlab_1.x = 719.95;
       iqlab_1.y = 155.25;
       iqlab1.play();
      score+=10;
      skor.text = " " + score;
     }

    if (ikhsya_1.hitTestObject(ikhsyabox_1))
     {
       ikhsya_1.enabled = false;
       //idsya_1.visible = false;
       ikhsya_1.buttonMode = false;
       ikhsya_1.x = 459.95;
       ikhsya_1.y = 198.75;
      ikhsya1.play();
      score+=10;
      skor.text = " " + score;
     }
```

Idsya1, Iqlab1, and Ikhsya1 is a sound from a library..idsya_1, ikhsya_1 and iqlab_1 is a movieclip.

my problem is when idsya_1 hit idsyabox_1 then the idsya1 sound will playing, and it worked, but when ikhsya_1 hit ikhsyabox_1  the sound playing is ikhsya1 and idsya1 too, and when iqlab_1 hit iqlabbox_1 then all the sound will playing..why is this happen??

I mean when idsya_1 hit idsyabox_1 then the sound playing is idsya1 sound

when iqlab_1 hit iqlabbox_1 then the sound playing is iqlab1 sound

and when ikhsya_1 hit ikhsyabox_1 the sound playing is ikhsya1 sound

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're checking for collision in a loop and everytime that loop fires it checks if there's collision for each of your strange named `MovieClips` and plays sound accordingly. If you want to play sounds one time for each try having `Boolean` properties to test if it's been played or not. So you'd have something like this:

```
if (iqlab_1.hitTestObject(iqlabbox_1) && !iqlab_1SoundHasPlayed) // checking if the sound has already played
 {
   iqlab_1.enabled = false;
//   iqlab_1.visible = false;
   iqlab_1.buttonMode = false;
   iqlab_1.x = 719.95;
   iqlab_1.y = 155.25;
   iqlab1.play();
  score+=10;
  skor.text = " " + score;

  iqlab_1SoundHasPlayed = true;
 }
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but the problem was changed to the movieclip that dragged back to its original position, if there might be any other way??

Comment: Provide more helpful explanation, otherwise I'm afraid I can't help you out more.

Comment: but thanks for your answer, I just have to add other functions to complete :)